# Trying to run Django, Redis, Celery and Supervisor on Ubuntu 18.04 but not working

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, supervisord

Hi I have made an application where I pull data and display in real time on my website.

On local, it works perfectly fine when I run the following:

```
celery -A proj_name beat -l INFO

celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -p gevent
```

I use gevent because I am on Windows. On the Ubuntu server, I do not think I would need that.

So now on the server, I have followed the below article to the letter:

```
https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/#running-remotely
```

When I get to the last part:

```
sudo supervisorctl start pichacelery
```

it gives me the following error:

```
bscscanapicelery: ERROR (no such file)
```

These are my files:

bscscanapi_celery.conf

```
; ==================================
;  celery worker supervisor example
; ==================================

; the name of your supervisord program
[program:bscscanapicelery]

; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/home/djangoadmin/.virtualenvs/bscscanapi/bin/celery worker -A bscscanapi --loglevel=INFO

; The directory to your Django project
directory=/home/djangoadmin/stalker-nichan/bscscanapi

; If supervisord is run as the root user, switch users to this UNIX user account
; before doing any processing.
user=djangoadmin

; Supervisor will start as many instances of this program as named by numprocs
numprocs=1

; Put process stdout output in this file
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/bscscanapi_worker.log

; Put process stderr output in this file
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/bscscanapi_worker.log

; If true, this program will start automatically when supervisord is started
autostart=true

; May be one of false, unexpected, or true. If false, the process will never
; be autorestarted. If unexpected, the process will be restart when the program
; exits with an exit code that is not one of the exit codes associated with this
; process’ configuration (see exitcodes). If true, the process will be
; unconditionally restarted when it exits, without regard to its exit code.
autorestart=true

; The total number of seconds which the program needs to stay running after
; a startup to consider the start successful.
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if your broker is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

bscscanapi_celerybeat.conf

```
; ================================
;  celery beat supervisor example
; ================================

; the name of your supervisord program
[program:bscscanapicelerybeat]

; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/home/djangoadmin/.virtualenvs/bscscanapi/bin/celery beat -A bscscanapi --loglevel=INFO

; The directory to your Django project
directory=/home/djangoadmin/stalker-nichan/bscscanapi

; If supervisord is run as the root user, switch users to this UNIX user account
; before doing any processing.
user=djangoadmin

; Supervisor will start as many instances of this program as named by numprocs
numprocs=1

; Put process stdout output in this file
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/bscscanapi_beat.log

; Put process stderr output in this file
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/bscscanapi_beat.log

; If true, this program will start automatically when supervisord is started
autostart=true

; May be one of false, unexpected, or true. If false, the process will never
; be autorestarted. If unexpected, the process will be restart when the program
; exits with an exit code that is not one of the exit codes associated with this
; process’ configuration (see exitcodes). If true, the process will be
; unconditionally restarted when it exits, without regard to its exit code.
autorestart=true

; The total number of seconds which the program needs to stay running after
; a startup to consider the start successful.
startsecs=10

; if your broker is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=999
```

Comment: Please confirm are you running `sudo supervisorctl start pichacelery` or `sudo supervisorctl start bscscanapicelery` ...??

Comment: I am running sudo supervisorctl start bscscanapicelery. Confirm.